# The ReplayKit doesn't work in my Objective-C code

Tags: ios, ios9

Does any one know how to use ReplayKit in Objective-C?

To use the ReplayKit in my code I follow the api implement the `RPScreenRecoderDelegate`, `RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate` in my `appDelegate`.

```
#import <ReplayKit/ReplayKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,
                                    NSURLConnectionDelegate,
                                    UIAlertViewDelegate,
                                    MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,
                                    RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate,
                                    RPScreenRecorderDelegate>
{}
```

Then in my game view, I click my "Record" button to trigger Recording, like this way:

```
- (void)StartRecording
{
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder =  RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;
    recorder.delegate = self;
    [recorder startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:YES handler:^(NSError *error) {

        if(error)
        {
            [self ShowRecordAlert:error.localizedDescription];
        }
    }];
}
```

Use "stop_btn" to stop recording screen:

```
- (void)StopRecording
{
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;

    [recorder stopRecordingWithHandler:^(RPPreviewViewController * previewViewController, 
NSError * error) {

        if(error)
        {
            [self ShowRecordAlert:error.localizedDescription];
        }

        if(previewViewController)
        {
            previewViewController.previewControllerDelegate = self;

            TiIOSDevice* device = (TiIOSDevice*)Game::Get()->GetDevice();
            UIViewController* con = (UIViewController*)device->GetViewController();

            previewViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

            [con presentViewController:previewViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }

    }];
}


//Implements two callbacks to capture the error:

- (void)screenRecorder:(RPScreenRecorder *)screenRecorder
            didStopRecordingWithError:(NSError *)error
            previewViewController:(RPPreviewViewController *)previewViewController
{
    if(error)
    {
        [self ShowRecordAlert:error.localizedDescription];
    }
}

- (void)previewControllerDidFinish:(RPPreviewViewController *)previewController
{
    [previewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However, when I touched the '"Record" or "Stop_btn"`, the corresponding  handler was not enter.

I print the `sharedRecorder.recording` value and  `sharedRecorder.microphoneEnable` value, they both return false.

I don't know which step is lost, please give me some advice.

Answer (score 3):

To answer Veslam's question, here's how you do it.  Say you have your own AppDelegate with a window property:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow* myWindow;
```

Inside the MyAppDelegate.mm file, you'll initialize myWindow like you were probably doing before, maybe in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  Then you have to define the setter for the AppDelegate's window property, like so:

```
-(UIWindow*) window
{
  // this is necessary so that ReplayKit can display its popup window
  return myWindow;
}
```

This will fix the "AppDelegate UIWindow:unrecognized selector to instance" error when you try to start recording.

Comment: Wow, I happened to find this answer to my own question, after hundreds of days I asked that! Now I'll restart my attemption, thanks a lot and another lot! XD

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed yesterday. The appDelegate must keep a UIWindow instance, or else it will throw an exception:

> appDelegate UIWindow:unrecognized selector to instance

Comment: Could you please explain the solution in detail? I think I got stuck by similar problem, but my instance of UIWindow does exist... :/ Thanks!